# Customized ServiceAuthenticationManager in WCF service not working on Windows 2008 R2 webserver

Tags: c#, security

I've added a custom authentification on a WCF service in order to validate all incoming requests using an override of the ServiceAuthenticationManager.
Everything works great on my own developer PC but when deployed to a Windows 2008 R2 webserver the ServiceAuthenticationManager override is never fired. Spend many hours searching for an answer but I'm stuck.

Here is my code:

```
namespace FDC.IHI.WebServices.VirtualInsuranceCard
{
    public class ServiceAuthorization : ServiceAuthorizationManager
    {
        private bool VerifyAuthorizationHeader(string authorizationHeader, string userName, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                var convertedString = Convert.FromBase64String(authorizationHeader);
                var svcCredentials = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII
                    .GetString(convertedString)
                    .Split(':');
                var authorizationHeaderCredentials = new { Name = svcCredentials[0], Password = svcCredentials[1] };
                if ((authorizationHeaderCredentials.Name == userName && authorizationHeaderCredentials.Password == password))
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }      
       
        protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
        {
            Core.ErrorHandler.ErrorHandler.LogText("ServiceAuthorizationManager triggered", "VIC");
            var authHeader = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Headers["Authorization"];
            if ((authHeader != null) && (authHeader != string.Empty))
            {
                var correctCredentials = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CredentialsVicService"].Split(';').Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToList();
                if (VerifyAuthorizationHeader(authHeader.Substring(6), correctCredentials[0], correctCredentials[1]))
                    return true;
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                //No authorization header was provided, so challenge the client to provide before proceeding:
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm=\"vicService\"");
                WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BindingServices">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>      
    </bindings>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>       
        <behavior name="RestHttp">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>        
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BehaviourServices">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceAuthorization serviceAuthorizationManagerType="FDC.IHI.WebServices.VirtualInsuranceCard.ServiceAuthorization, FDC.IHI.WebServices" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>    

    <services>
      <service name="VirtualInsuranceCard.VicService" behaviorConfiguration="BehaviourServices">
        <endpoint behaviorConfiguration="RestHttp" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BindingServices" contract="VirtualInsuranceCard.iVicService" />
      </service>
    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

It really puzzles me that it works as expected when run through my developer platform but not when running on webserver. The webserver responds with an answer so the web service business code is triggered, but the authentification is ignored i.e. the ServiceAuthenticationManager is never fired.
This makes me think that it may have something to do with IIS settings on the webserver that I deployed the code to but I can't seem to find anything missing here though.

Comment: Is your URL HTTP or HTTPS (secure)?  Most likely the server want HTTPS and the TLS authentication is failing (serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true").  Can you login using a webpage?  TLS can fail for many reasons based on the Version of Net you are using.

Comment: Hi jdweng. Both my developer PC IIS and the webserver IIS have the webserver hosted with https bindings. I'm using the same certificate on both.

Comment: The webservice on the webserver replies with a 200 and an usable answer so I don't think that TLS/HTTPS is the problem (but i maybe wrong?), however the Authentication header seems to be ignored.

Comment: Yes 200 OK means everything is working.  Sounds like the 2008 R2 is returning different data than what you are expecting.  You need to capture the response message to see what is wrong.

Comment: I tried testing the webservice through PostMan and here I get the expected result. A 401 if the Authorization key is wrong and a 200 + valid output if the key i correct. But if i make a simple webrequest against the same webservice using an aspx page the response is a 200 + the output even when the autorization key is invalid. The webservice should not deliver the output if the key is incorrect. This is what the result of my PostMan test tells me, but it does nevertheless. This is really a mystery to me

Comment: The default HTTP headers are different in c# than in Postman.  Usually the solution is to make the c# headers look exactly the same as Postman.  Often it is just the UserAgent that needs to be changed.

Comment: I agree, but i worries me that it is possible to create a simple webrequest and bypass the authorization. If I can do that, anyone can. The webservice should not return data, if the authorization is not applied or is not correct. So I don't belive I solved the issue yet.

Answer (score 0):

After painstakingly going through every corner of my source code and trying to figure out differences between my local IIS and IIS on the webserver I finally figured it out :)
On the remote webserver the hosts file pointed to a different webserver for the endpoint I was trying to reach thereby executing an older version of my webservice code.
Doh!! A lot of hours lost. Wonder if I learned anything here?
I had no idear the hosts file had been changed but learned that this was because someone else in the organization was testing a new webserver to replace the old 2008 R2 version.

Thanks for your effort jdweng :)